# Usando variáveis

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estava de olho no uso de variáveis no CSS, como abaixo, coisa simples, até ai tudo bem. Depois vi que dava para incorporar 'funções', mas só vi fazendo o uso de libs como [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) e [sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

É possível definir uma função no CSS - como os 2 últimos exemplos - sem precisar recorrer à libs instaladas?

Facilitaria mais a manutenção da folha de estilo do que ter que definir várias classes aos elementos, tipo `<div class="azul borda maiusculo">Lorem ipsum</div>`.

---

```
:root {
  --preto:#000;
  --cinza:#999;
}

h1{color:var(--preto)}
h2{color:var(--cinza)}


<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
```

---

```
.classH1(@color: red, @size: 16px){
    font-size:@size;
    border:@color 2px solid;
}

h1{
    .classH1(green, 20px);
}
```

---

```
.classH1(){
    font-size:10;
    border:#000 2px solid;
}

h1{
    .classH1();
}
```

Comment: Eu não conheço funções que façam isso, apenas com Less ou Sass.. algumas funções do CSS: [W3Schools CSS Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_functions.asp)

Comment: Eu recomendo usar LESS ou SASS com editor Visual Studio Code, lá tem um plugin(easy less) que ao salvar seu arquivo LESS já gera o CSS no mesmo diretório

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno obrigado, vou dar uma olhada pra ver.

Comment: Cara acho que isso vai te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298995/o-que-significa-o-especificado-no-root-do-css-do-bootstrap/298998#298998 da pra fazer muita coisa com variável

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O conceito de funções já existe no CSS, mas não da maneira que você deseja. As funções que podem ser utilizadas são nativas à linguagem e não há como definir novas sem a utilização de linguagens auxiliares, tais como SASS e LESS, que quando compiladas geram um código CSS.

A lista de funções nativas do CSS até este momento pode ser encontrada [aqui](http://www.quackit.com/css/functions/) (fonte não oficial), com uma documentação interessante para cada.

Comment: Nas variáveis só posso ter `:root { --preto:#000 }` e não posso usar uma lista tipo `:root { font-size:10; border:#000 2px solid }`, certo?

Comment: @PapaCharlie certo, você só consegue definir o valor de uma propriedade em cada variável; não é possível definir o estilo da fonte e da borda com a mesma, por exemplo. Porém, ter `--border: #000 2px solid` e `border: var(--border)` é algo completamente válido e funcional.

Comment: O código das libs é compilado pelo javascript?

Comment: Varia conforme a ferramenta. SASS utiliza Ruby (há o Gulp Sass que é em Node), LESS utiliza Node, que é JavaScript, inclusive com a opção de *compilar* direto no navegador (em ambiente de desenvolvimento). Compass também utiliza Ruby. Stylus também utiliza Node.